# Install mutter-rounded

Tags: 22.10, mutter

I have recently upgraded my ubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10. I'm trying to customize it but mutter-rounded is not supported on 22.10, is there any other packages that I can use as alternative of mutter-rounded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realized you updated from an LTS with 5 years of support to an interim release with 9 months of support as you app does not run you may want to rethink this.

Comment: Thanks @David and I approciate it. I just wanted to try the new one. However, I have found a solution for that. The GNOME extension `Rounded Window Corners` fixed the issue for me though it don't have the  window blur effects. It's certeinly done my work.